# How can I specify /debug:embedded from csproj?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, visual-studio-2017

I've authored a dotnet core library, which is packaged using NuGet. I want to embed the debug information (and the source code if that's possible) in the dll. rather than have a separate symbols package.

According to https://github.com/ctaggart/SourceLink it looks like this is possible when invoking the compiler directly by specifying some switches to the compiler. I don't understand how the csproj file relates to invocation of the compiler.

How can I specify the flag /debug:embedded from the csproj?

Here's my csproj:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>KamailioApi</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>KamailioApi</PackageId>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.1</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
    <!-- don't change this we hack it in the TeamCity Build-->
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.1-beta</PackageVersion>    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlDocument" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="system.xml.xpath.xmldocument" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.6' ">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Requests" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714352/embedding-c-sharp-sources-in-pdb-with-new-csproj/42759457#42759457

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with the [`<DebugSymbols>` and `<DebugType>` properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties), like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>    
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[Here's an example of where I do it with MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/e160a25e4578554b3c8fab9f8116b79abaa04837/src/Directory.build.props#L23-L24), note that `Directory.build.props` applies to all `.csproj` files at or below that directory level so you can specify common things in larger projects one time.

Comment: do you know, where the default value of DebugSymbols is documented? Could not find it and it is not in your link

Comment: The `<DebugSymbols>` property controls whether a `.pdb` file will be created, but it isn't necessary for `<DebugType>embedded` to work in C# 6.0 or higher (because `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` passes `<Csc DebugType="$(DebugType)" EmitDebugInformation="$(DebugSymbols)">`, [which are both handled here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/8e4ab418a8f9703f7dfe3a66adc9b3876ef9382f/src/Compilers/Core/MSBuildTask/ManagedCompiler.cs#L175) - `DebugType` ends-up in `/debug:{value}` and is more specific than `DebugSymbols` (which ends up as just a toggle for`/debug`).