# why is source generated code invisible to debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, auto-generate, c#-11.0

I'm testing a Maui app that uses CommuniytToolkit.Mvvm to generate [ObservableProperty] attributes. The ViewModel partial class is generated for Android and Windows; I can see it in Dependencies, but the Debugger can't find it and prompts for it. The problem is generated code is in-memory only, not a file. The debugger works for Android but can't find the generated code on Windows.

I haven't been able to find a workaround so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714352/embedding-c-sharp-sources-in-pdb-with-new-csproj

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding C# sources in PDB with new csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714352/embedding-c-sharp-sources-in-pdb-with-new-csproj)

Comment: Hi Gary, does Guru's answer answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles` element (and potentially `CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath`) to the .csproj. Something like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>path_to_output_folder</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Read more:

- [Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview#get-started-with-source-generators) intro article