Why is VS modifying my code when debugging using .net8
Can someone help me with this.  I've been compiling this code for years and for some reason there is some funny business now with .net8
My code hits an exception in some code that, apparently, was converted into an "extracted embedded document" and was MODIFIED during the "extraction" to REMOVE a crucial line in my code which is causing my exception error.  Why is VS messing with me?
On the left of the screenshot is my actual code.  On the right is the F'd up "extracted" document.  Notice the crucial line that is missing. In the Output window you can see where VS fesses up to messing with me.
Any help will be appreciated, regards,
James


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714352/embedding-c-sharp-sources-in-pdb-with-new-csproj
